# Input Group Buttons with dropdowns not working in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the twitter bootstrap to show input with dropdown button as mentioned in http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Below is the complete html same the one specified in the sample, But I am unable to get this working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!-- /btn-group -->
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div><!-- /input-group -->
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!-- /btn-group -->
                    </div><!-- /input-group -->
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Request anyone to point out what is going on wrong as the dropdown is missing?

Thanks in Advance,
-Senthil

Comment: Why is it not working? What is happening and what are you expecting?

Comment: The dropdown is not appearing on click of the action button which is what I am expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `bootstrap js`

Add this `js` in your `<head>` section

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This resolved the issue. I had to include both JQuery.js and bootstrap.js <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add a "data-target" attribute to the button and an "id" to the dropdown.

`<button data-target="#MYIDHERE" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action</button>`

`<ul id="MYIDHERE" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
 <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
</ul>`